# EXTJS 4 MVC Architecture

Tags: extjs4.1

Am working in EXTJS 4.1 MVC Architecture. Am completely new to this, and i was thinking if there is a way of having multiple stores in a store file.

For example, we have the two directories, model and store, and each of these have files. Am having a file named Locations.js inside the store folder. Adn i want to define three stores inside this file. eg: 'Regions', 'Area', 'City'

So, first when i try to do define the first store, the firebug shows error cannot find store/regions.js file. Whereas the file it should look for is actually Locations.js file.
Is there a way of resolving this, or is it that the store name and the file name should be the same, and that we can have only store in a file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'define the first store'? In the controller?

Comment: I just meant that the programme is trying to find app/store/Regions.js instead of trying to locate the store 'regions' inside app/store/Locations.js

Comment: He means instantiate the store, which triggers the Loader to fetch the corresponding file, which it can't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Loader only knows how to find classes in their own files. You could do it by manually loading the files, but that's more trouble than it's worth, and you'll lose Ext's ability to build a dependency tree and minify with the SDK tools.

Stick to one class per file. You can go as deep as you want though, so your file system could have the following:

```
App/store/location/Region.js
App/store/location/Area.js
App/store/location/City.js
```

Just make sure your classes have corresponding names. (e.g. `App.store.location.Region`)
You can then even have a base `App.store.location.Location` that all others extend. If this is a big project, I've also found it useful to subclass Ext.data.Store right from the start (make `App.store.Store`) and make sure all of your stores extend that.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `Ext.loader`. It provides a system of loading 'classes' dynamically. So yes when you have an object `MyApp.store.Regions` it's expected to be in the file inside the store folder.

But this shouldn't be a big problem. You can use the sencha build tool to minify in 1 file.

You can also [disable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-enabled) the loader and do the loading manually. (but I don't recommend that)